# Can AWS CloudFront be used without ec2 server

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

My wordpress websites are hosted on a different registrar's VPS server. My question is can i still use AWS Cloudfront for CDN?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can.

> Q. Does Amazon CloudFront work with non-AWS origin servers?
>
> Yes. Amazon CloudFront works with any origin server that holds the original, definitive versions of your content, both static and dynamic. There is no additional charge to use a custom origin.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/details/

Note that if your current provider charges you for bandwidth, you will still be paying them for some bandwidth as needed to deliver the content to CloudFront as it is requested. (CloudFront doesn't fetch content from your server unless and until a viewer actually requests that  specific content.)  When your servers are in EC2, the charge for bandwidth out of EC2 into CloudFront is $0.

Comment: To add to this, if your caching headers aren't configured correctly and CloudFront downloads content each time you'll pay for bandwidth twice, and AWS bandwidth is fairly expensive. Lightsail bandwidth is fairly cheap, I suspect you could use it as a reverse proxy to an EC2 server.